# Column `token` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 3

Tags: r

I'm trying to tokenizer long sentences:

```
dat <- data.frame(text = c("hi i am Apple, not an orange. that is an orange","hello i am banana, not an pineapple. that is an pineapple"),
                  received = c(1, 0))

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(token = sent_detect(text, language = "en"))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Column `token` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 3
```

This is because the str_detect [function](https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/9ace6002cc758d5a303a) returns a list of sentences that doesn't map back to the length original dataframe.

```
library(openNLP)
library(NLP)

sent_detect <- function(text, language) {
  # Function to compute sentence annotations using the Apache OpenNLP Maxent sentence detector employing the default model for language 'en'. 
  sentence_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language)

  # Convert text to class String from package NLP
  text <- as.String(text)

  # Sentence boundaries in text
  sentence.boundaries <- annotate(text, sentence_token_annotator)

  # Extract sentences
  sentences <- text[sentence.boundaries]

  # return sentences
  return(sentences)
}
```

I'm looking into purrr::map, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this situation.

I'm expecting a result that looks like this:

```
text                                                    received    token
"hi i am Apple, not an orange. that is an orange"           1       "hi i am Apple, not an orange."
"hi i am Apple, not an orange. that is an orange"           1       "that is an orange"
"hello i am banana, not an pineapple. that is an pineapple" 0       "hello i am banana, not an pineapple."
"hello i am banana, not an pineapple. that is an pineapple" 0       "that is an pineapple"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyr + purrr gets you there. `map` will create a nested output which you can bring to a higher level with `unnest` from tidyr.

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(sentences = purrr::map(text, sent_detect, "en")) %>% 
  unnest(sentences)


# A tibble: 4 x 3
  text                                                      received sentences                           
  <chr>                                                        <dbl> <chr>                               
1 hi i am Apple, not an orange. that is an orange                  1 hi i am Apple, not an orange.       
2 hi i am Apple, not an orange. that is an orange                  1 that is an orange                   
3 hello i am banana, not an pineapple. that is an pineapple        0 hello i am banana, not an pineapple.
4 hello i am banana, not an pineapple. that is an pineapple        0 that is an pineapple
```